# MVC, How to pass TextBoxFor value to Controller Action and write result back to view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Good day. I am new to MVC and I was wondering how can I get this right, i want a user to populate a textbox with an account number, when the user finishes entering the account number an event must trigger an MVC Action and pass that value to the controller, perform validation and get the result back to the view and populate result in other text boxes. My scenario is that I pass an account number to a web service which then validates the account number and then get 3 additional fields(company name, company reg number and postal code) and fill them in the textboxes. Please see what I have so far and I would appreciate your assistance.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EmmAccountVerification(RegisterViewModel model)
    {

        customerDetail_PortTypeClient client = new customerDetail_PortTypeClient();
        var accountnumber = model.EMMAccount;
        var results = client.getCustomerContactDetails(accountnumber);

        if (results != null)
        {
           model.CompanyRegistrationNumber = results.companyRegistartionNo;
           model.CompanyName = results.fullName;
            //results.companyRegistartionNo = model.CompanyRegistrationNumber;
            //results.fullName = model.CompanyName;
        }
        return Json(model);
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form",id = "regform" }))


@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EMMAccount, new { @placeholder = "example: 0123456789", @class = "form-control", @type = "number", id = "txtA" , onkeypress = "capLock(event)",onblur = "CallWebService()" })
```

Script

```
function CallWebService() {
        debugger;
        $("#txtA").blur(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/EmmAccountVerification/Home",
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#regForm").serialize(),
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (model) {
                $("#companyname").val(model.CompanyName);
                $("#companyRegNum").val(model.CompanyRegistrationNumber);
                $("#PostalCode").val(model.PostalCode);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Your action is marked as `[HttpGet]`, but your AJAX call tries to find a POST action. Therefore your Action will not be hit. Also the url does not seem to be right, it schould probably be `/{Controller}/{Action}`. If the JS is part of the Razor View, you can create the correct url using the UrlHelper: `"@Url.Action("EmmAccountVerification", "Home")"`.

Comment: In addition to Georg's comment, if this is .net core then you'll need to add `[FromBody]` in front of the variable in the method signature.  So it would be `public ActionResult EmmAccountVerification([FromBody] RegisterViewModel model)`.

Comment: Also, `$.serialize` returns an `x-www-form-urlencoded` string, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you need to create the model for your post method and set value to it and [ass it to the post request

```
var RegisterViewMode = { "EMMAccount": document.getElementById('txtA').value };
```

Your code will look link-

```
function CallWebService() {
    debugger;
    $("#txtA").blur(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/EmmAccountVerification/Home",
            type: "POST",
            data: RegisterViewMode ,
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (model) {
            $("#companyname").val(model.CompanyName);
            $("#companyRegNum").val(model.CompanyRegistrationNumber);
            $("#PostalCode").val(model.PostalCode);
        });
    });
```